# Querying a single field within a Jinja2 template

Tags: flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm working on an application where users can enter work requests, and subsequently go in and search for requests.  The issue I'm having is building out the request summary screen.  Basically, it lists the results of a search query.  The snippet from the template is as such:

```
        {% for req in workrequests %}
            {{ req.id }} {{ req.customer }} {{ req.dateEntered }} {{ req.Contact }}
        {% endfor %}
```

Here's wher I get hung up.  The req.customer, and req.Contact fields are just keys for the customer and contact databases.  I want to display the customer name and contact name.  I assume the following queries should do the trick:

```
        Customer.query.filter_by(req.customer).one()
        Contact.query.filter_by(req.Contact).one()
```

Problem is, that will return the entire record.  I'm just after the name field from both of those tables to put into my template, which is where the problem is.  I'm not sure how to proceed with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Customer.query` is a short form of `db.session.query(Customer)`. Use the latter to query for specific columns:

```
db.session.query(Customer.name).filter_by(id=req.customer).one()
```

Although I think that what you really want is a single query that gets all the data at once. Something like:

```
db.session.query(
    WorkRequest.id,
    WorkRequest.dateEntered,
    Customer.name,
    Contact.name
).join(
    Customer,
    Contact
).filter(...)
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  I forgot that I could turn around and use the db.session itself.